# Pass amount from Stripe checkout for to view function in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, stripe-payments

I have several classes we sell and I am setting up Stripe.  Everything works great if I have just one class with a fixed price in the view, but I have 6 classes I need to be able to charge for.  Can I pass the value from the template form to the view so I can charge different amounts with the same view?

Here is my code that works for a single class:

**view**

```
def charge(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return redirect('training')

    if 'stripeToken' not in request.POST:
        messages.error(request, 'Uh oh, something went wrong, please try again!')
        return redirect('training_classes')

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.POST['stripeEmail'],
        source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
    )

    amount = 2000

    stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer.id,
        currency='usd',
        amount=amount,
        description='Food Handlers Card'
    )

    messages.success(request, 'Success')
    return redirect('training')
```

form

```
<form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ key }}"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Food & beverage Association of San Diego County"
    data-description="Food Handlers Card"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-allow-remember-me="false"
    data-label="Pay As Member">
  </script>
</form>
```

I'm going to need a few of these forms for the classes we offer but they are different prices.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to add additional inputs in the form that contains Stripe Checkout to pass additional values back to your controller:

```
<form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2000"></input?
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ key }}"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Food & beverage Association of San Diego County"
    data-description="Food Handlers Card"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-allow-remember-me="false"
    data-label="Pay As Member">
  </script>
</form>
```

However that is generally not considered secure as the customer could just modify the amount.

What you generally want to do is pass some information about what the customer is buying (like the SKU / product code) and pass that as the hidden input, or even better save that information in some sort of server-side session state.

Server side you'd access any of these values via the `request.POST` dictionary such as `request.POST['amount']`

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I added `FHC_CHARGE_M = 3000` to my settings file, then `'fhc_charge_m': settings.FHC_CHARGE_M,` to my page view inside a return request and then `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ fhc_charge_m }}"/>` to my form.  It passes the amount in but now just stuck on how to pass it to the 'amount' variable in the view.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: You just passed the amount into the view though. data-amount="{{ fhc_charge_m }} would work just as well

Comment: maybe I am losing it...I can pass it there yes and it shows in the pop-up window, but the charge view definition has an 'amount' variable that needs to be set.  How do I pass the data-amount from the form to the 'amount' variable in the view.  Does this make sense?  Sorry if I'm not being too clear, I am still a bit of a hack :) Thank  you again.

Comment: Ah the view function is what most people would call the "controller", reading the input would just be request.POST['amount'],  (aka whatever the "name" is)

Comment: That is funny, I was just about to comment that I figured it out... If it wasn't for your original response to my post, I wouldn't have looked for a solution in this direction.  Can you put the solution in a response I can accept as the correct answer? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Matthew, if you put your last response as part of your first answer, I can accept it as the right answer; as they were both crucial for my solution.

Comment: should be at the bottom "Server side you'd access any of these values via the request.POST dictionary such as request.POST['amount']"